# EclipseLink & PostgreSQL doesn't use BIGSERIAL to Long id

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

i expected below code to create table which has BIGSERIAL column type id.

```
@Entity
public class NewEntity1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
...
```

but it created:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWENTITY1 (ID  SERIAL NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
```

i want to make it BIGSERIAL column (not SERIAL). how can i fix this?

my environment:

- NetBeans7.1
- GlassFish 3.1.1(NetBeans bundled)
- EclipseLink 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504(NetBeans bundled)
- PostgreSQL 9.1.2 (JDBC driver: postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that EclipseLink PostgreSQLPlatform hard codes the string it uses within the printFieldIdentityClause to be "SERIAL".  This should be customizable though, so please file a bug to have it changed.

Other than using columnDefinition, you can create a sublclass of the PostgreSQLPlatform and override the printFieldIdentityClause method to print off what you need.  Ie:

```
@Override
    public void printFieldIdentityClause(Writer writer) throws ValidationException {
        try {
            writer.write(" SERIAL");
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            throw ValidationException.fileError(ioException);
        }
    }
```

and then set your persistence unit properties to use your platform class instead:

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="yourpackage.yourPlatformClass"/>
```

Comment: thanks. filed(URL: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371850). BTW, i have changed my mind to use SequenceGenerator or TableGenerator. it works fine with Long & BIGINT column type, and i think it's more cross-platform way than override columnDefinition.

Answer (score 1):

do not user 'Long' to define the id type , but 'BigInteger' instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use columnDefinition to point to BIGSERIAL instead of default mapping type.

Example:

```
@Entity
public class NewEntity1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGSERIAL")
    private Long id;
```

Comment: thanks, it almost worked, but it overridden all of column definition, so nullable foreign key references would be can't exist (it caused: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "newentity1_id" violates not-null constraint). any other suggestions?

Comment: add in the "NOT NULL" constraint to the column definition string. ie columnDefinition = "BIGSERIAL NOT NULL");

Comment: it caused all foreign keys to not nullable. i mean, if define like that, foreign key definitions are became BIGSERIAL too, but i don't want that (i want foreign key definitions to remain "BIGINT NULL").

Comment: The type on the id is used as a default for the FKs so you will need to specify the columnDefinition="BIGSERIAL" on all foreign key joincolumns referencing this id to override the "BIGSERIAL NOT NULL" that it will use as a default from the id.  I'll put an alternative as a seperate answer.